# Trigger - Insert into audit, prevent update on live table

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

First post here.

I want to create a trigger so that when someone tries to update the table it prevents the update and logs the attempt in an audit table.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [Person].[Lastname_Trigger]
ON [Person].[Person]
FOR UPDATE AS
       IF UPDATE (Lastname)
       BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO SurnameChange (BusinessEntityID, Firstname, OldLastName, NewLastName,AttemptedBy, Timestamped)
             SELECT
                d.businessentityid,
                i.firstname,
                d.lastname,
                i.lastname,
                SUSER_SNAME(),
                GETDATE()
             FROM deleted d , inserted i
             WHERE d.businessentityid = i.businessentityid
       END 

       /*This is where it is going wrong*/
       BEGIN TRANSACTION
          IF UPDATE(lastname)
          BEGIN
              RAISERROR ('cannot change lastname', 16, 1)
              ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
              RETURN
          END
```

If anyone can help me out that would be great, I've used AdventureWorks for the example so it's generic and usable for others.

Many thanks.

James

Comment: An [`INSTEAD OF` trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx) may be easier here; as the name suggests, whatever you put in the trigger runs instead of the triggering action, so the original `INSERT` will not be executed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [Person].[Lastname_Trigger]
ON [Person].[Person]
FOR UPDATE AS
       IF UPDATE (Lastname)
       BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO SurnameChange (BusinessEntityID, Firstname, OldLastName, NewLastName,AttemptedBy, Timestamped)
             SELECT
                d.businessentityid,
                i.firstname,
                d.lastname,
                i.lastname,
                SUSER_SNAME(),
                GETDATE()
             FROM deleted d
             INNER JOIN inserted i ON d.businessentityid = i.businessentityid

          RAISERROR ('cannot change lastname', 16, 1)
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
       END

       RETURN
```

I don't see any reason to (a) check *again* if `LastName` has been updated, and (b) there's really no need to start a transaction inside the trigger.

Since you want to **prevent** the actual `UPDATE` from happening - just `ROLLBACK` the transaction that's already *in progress* (for the `UPDATE` command) and be done with it.

Side note: please *upgrade* your SQL know-how to the "new" proper ANSI SQL `JOIN` syntax (introduced **over 20 years ago** with the SQL-92 standard) - use `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc. and stop using the comma-separated list of tables

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it would be something simple.

Comment: no problem.  Still getting used to the website so thanks for pointing it out should I post again.